# PHP converting array

Tags: php, arrays

I have such question 
I have this array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 164
            [ID] => 164
            [1] => 1368840229
            [TIME] => 1368840229
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 69
            [TOPIC_ID] => 69
            [1] => 1368841037
            [TIME] => 1368841037
        )

)
```

I want the result should be as

```
Array
(
    [164] => 1368840229
    [69] => 1368841037
)
```

how to do this? 
thanks!

///////// 
How much do I have to write in order for stackoverflow to allow me to post?
///////////

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: I am not a professional and just learning
I read the php manual, searched the internet and tried to solve it myself, about 4 hours, but without success.

so I asked here.

Comment: @John Conde: I agree and disagree. Yes when I read questions, I like to feel that I'm helping, and not just doing the work for someone else. BUT, I also like questions to be concise, clear, and well explained... I don't want to be drowned in unsuccessful attempts: it waste my time as a reader.

Comment: This is actually a valuable and hard question - even most professionals cannot do it. It involves creating two separated arrays from the original arrays and then merge them. I am also doing the research on array conversion. PHP is not particularly efficient on such task. Node.js on the other hand seems to be easier to work with for what you tried to do.

Answer (score 2):

This should work based on your example:

```
foreach($inputArray as $value) {
  $outputArray[$value[0]]=$value[1];
}
print($outputArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

is that what you are looking for ?

```
foreach($myArray as $key=>$row) {
  $finalArray[$row['ID']]=$row['TIME'];
}
```

Comment: since you don't actually use the key, you can use the syntax `foreach($myArray as $row) {`....

Comment: Except the second array uses TOPIC_ID instead of ID.